# Function template failed to use in Notebook context

Tags: functions, autocomplete, templates

For some reason, I need to set the Notebook context as the default context. And I follow the methods in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/MakeTemplate.html to define a function template, for example:

```
func::usage = "func[a] is an example of a function";
func[a_] := a;
```

then type `func`, then type `ctrl + shift + K`, however, the usage information `func[a] is an example of a function` do not appear.

If I change the context to `Global`, it has no problem.

If I use a explicit context name, let say the Notebook context is `Notebook$$19$555715`, then use `` Notebook$$19$555715`func `` is also ok.

How can I get the frontend to show the function template in Notebook context? I use Mathematica 12.2 in Windows 10 20H2.

Comment: Did you select the `func` ?

Comment: Works for me in MMA 12.0 on Win10-64

Comment: @DanielHuber，I tried selected the `func` and then type `ctrl+shift+K`, it doesn't work too.

Comment: @MarcoB，Have you set the `CellContext` as `Notebook`? I tried in MMA 12.0 on Win10-64, but I find it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried again with both contexts. Strange, with context "Notebook" it did not work at first, but after a minute or so, it worked..

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, it is strange. I tried your methods. I find that if I first work with `Global` context and define a function `func1` with usage, and type `ctrl+shift+K` **twice**. Then change to `Notebook` context, and define `func1` again, the usage information of `func1` will work. Howerver, if I define another function `func2`, the usage information of `func2` doesn't work.  I guess the reason is that the usage information of `func1` has loaded to frontend when work with `Global` context.

Comment: I think this is a case where a complicated system shows some emerging features that the creator did not anticipate. Especially so, if time comes into play.